# setOnItemLongClickListener não está funcionando

Tags: android, listview, onclick

Alguém pode me ajudar dizendo pq o meu **setOnItemLongClickListener** não está sendo chamado quando eu dou um long click no item da minha lista?

Tenho no mesmo adapter 2 métodos do tipo onclick, um é o setOnItemClickListener e o outro é setOnItemLongClickListener, mas apenas o primeiro está funcionando, segue o código:

```
public class CategoriaAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
List<Categoria> lista;
private ListView listView;
private SubCategoria subcategoria = new SubCategoria();

public CategoriaAdapter(Context context, List<Categoria> lista, ListView listView) {
    this.context = context;
    this.lista = lista;
    this.listView = listView;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return lista.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return lista.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final int auxPosition = position;

    final Categoria categoria = new Categoria();


    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.categoria_row, null);

    final TextView categ = (TextView)
            layout.findViewById(R.id.tvCat);
    categ.setText(lista.get(position).getNome());


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, final long l) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alert.setTitle("Adicionar subcategoria");
            alert.setMessage("Digite um nome para a subcategoria:");

            Toast.makeText(context, "Item with id [" + l + "] - Position [" + i + "] ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            final EditText input = new EditText(context);
            alert.setView(input);


            alert.setPositiveButton("Adicionar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    //int idCategoria = (Integer) button.getTag();
                    int position = (int) l;

                    subcategoria.setNome(input.getText().toString());
                    subcategoria.setIdCategoria(position);


                    SubCategoriaDAO subCategoriaDAO = new SubCategoriaDAO(context);

                    subCategoriaDAO.inserir(subcategoria);
                }
            });

            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    return;
                }
            });

            alert.show();
        }
    });


    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            dialog.setTitle("Apagar categoria?");
            dialog.setMessage("Essa ação não poderá ser desfeita");

            dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    CategoriaDAO categoriaDAO = new CategoriaDAO(context);

                    categoriaDAO.deletar(categoria);
                }
            });

            dialog.setNegativeButton("Voltar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    return;
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });


    SubCategoriaDAO subcategoria = new SubCategoriaDAO(context);
    List<SubCategoria> list = subcategoria.getLista();
    ListView listView = (ListView) layout.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(new SubCategoriaAdapter(context, list, listView));


    return layout;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só esqueci de uma linha que já resolveu tudo:

```
dialog.show();
```

Funcionou na hora, mas agora ele chama o onItemClick e o onItemLongClick, os dois juntos, como resolver?

Comment: Só retornar `true` do `onItemLongClick`. Para entender melhor: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que definir setOnItemLongClickListener() no ListView:

```
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int pos, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.v("long clicked","pos: " + pos);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Para cada item na lista, O XML (você deve usar um XML personalizado) deve ter `android: longClickable = "true"`, bem como (ou você pode usar o método `listView.setLongClickable (true);`). Mas desta forma, você pode **ter uma lista com apenas alguns itens** que respondem a longclick.

Answer (score -1):

Cara, tente utilizar Log na sua aplicação, e assim saber onde está ocorrendo o erro!
No entanto, crie um método para colocar o AlertDialog, e assim você chama ele dentro desse método!

(desculpe colocar como resposta, mas não tenho pontos suficientes para comentar!)

Comment: Não tem erro @TaironeDias, ele não da qualquer mensagem nem nada, coloquei um Log.i no método porém ele não é chamado.